# What is the difference between MASM and NASM codes?

Tags: assembly, nasm, masm

I have macOS and I'm trying to figure out difference between MASM and NASM.

As I understand MASM works only for Windows systems, and NASM is is available for other platforms as well. NASM I can compile on my mac:

`nasm -f macho64 hello1.asm`

`ld -macosx_version_min 10.7.0 -o hello1 hello1.o`

`./hello1`

```
    global    start
    section   .text
start:
    mov       rax, 0x02000004
    mov       rdi, 1
    mov       rsi, message
    mov       rdx, 13
    syscall

    mov       rax, 0x02000001
    xor       rdi, rdi
    syscall 

    section   .data
message:  
    db        "Hello, World", 10
```

But to compile MASM I need to use `DOSBox`

`MASM.EXE HELLO2.ASM`

`LINK.EXE HELLO2.OJB`

`HELLO2.EXE`

```
DATA SEGMENT 
    MSG DB  "Hello, World!", "$"
DATA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT
    ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:DATA 
    ; INIT SEGMENT REGS 
    START:
        MOV AX, DATA 
        MOV DS, AX 

        MOV AH, 09H
        LEA DX, MSG     ; PRINT THE STRING
        INT 21H

    STOP:
        MOV AX, 4C00H
        INT 21H 
CODE ENDS 
    END START
```

My question may seem silly, but I want to figure it out. Do I understand correctly that `hello1` is `NASM`, and `hello2` is `MASM`? And if it is right, why can't I execute on `DOSBox` this:

```
.model SMALL
.386

.data
    tekst db "Hello World!\n"
.stack 100h
.code
    .startup
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, offset tekst
    mov edx, 13
    int 80h
        .exit
end
```

Comment: `int 21h` is a DOS system call, `int 80h` is a 32-bit Linux system call, `syscall` is apparently a 64-bit MacOS system call (may also be used by other systems).

Comment: Thanks, that makes things a little bit more clear. But what about `hello1` and `hello2` program? Do I understand it right that first one is NASM and second one is MASM?

Comment: @ecm: Yes, all mainstream x86-64 OSes use `syscall` as their system-call ABI.  MacOS is similar to Linux in using RAX = call number, but uses `0x02000000 | number` for that class of system calls, while Linux uses small numbers like `__NR_exit_group` = 231 and `__NR_write` = 1.  (For some basic system calls like read/write/exit, MacOS's call number happen to match the 32-bit Linux call numbers with that high bit set.)

Comment: Anyway, as you say, the key point is that system-call ABIs differ by OS, not by which assembler you use to build the code.  (JWASM might be able to build a working Linux 32-bit executable from the last code block, if it understands `.exit`, and probably stuff like `.stack` and `.model small` would need to be removed.  JWASM is a portable open-source MASM-syntax assembler.  I've never had any use for it; I find NASM syntax much better, and haven't needed to build existing MASM code.)